# How paper strips get electrified?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, forces, electrostatics, electricity

Why paper strips get electrified when we iron them? I have learned that when two insulators are rubbed then they gets electrified but in case of ironing a paper the iron is a conductor. Will rubbing a conductor with an insulator electrifies an insulator or both? Will the paper gets ionised due to heat and emits electrons into the atmosphere?

Answer (score 2):

The effect is due to polarization separation; since the paper is not a conductor, it has many bound charges at the surface.  You can polarize little bits of paper by simply rubbing them; then they stick to your hair, clothes, etc.

Ionization is not required.

Answer (score 1):

When you iron bits of paper, you are giving external energy in the form of heat to its atoms and it absorbs this energy, this phenomenon releases free ions which are loosely attached to its atom. This phenomenon is known as Ionization.

Comment: will the conductor also gets charged? What are these ions positive or negative?

Comment: The paper strips are negatively charged due to ionized electrons. But remember, here the charge is not due to induction but due to ionization so there is no conductor here.

Comment: so if they are negativily charged then why do they attract crt screens?

Comment: **Sorry** i made a mistake. its positively charged and the CRT 'screen' which is negatively charged attracts the positively charged paper strips.